# How to obtain GET request URL using chrome.webRequest API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I create a chrome extension which offer accessibility to download any media in opened page of Facebook, including photo, video, and story. But I'm stuck when about to access/catch facebook's video story request URL that's shown up in Network tab in console, using `chrome.webRequest` API.

[image]

By excluding `bytestart` and `byteend` params from URL above, we got the full video file (with an expiration token). The `<video>` tag itself has `src` attribute like `blob:https://www.facebook.com/<some_alpha_numerics_and_hyphens>`.

This is what I've tried in my extension project:

permission:

```
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "*://*/*"
],
```

I've tried to listen all the events available but no luck.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log('onBeforeRequest', details.url);
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  }
);
// onBeforeSendHeaders
// onSendHeaders
// onHeadersReceived
// onAuthRequired
// onResponseStarted
// onBeforeRedirect
// onCompleted
// onErrorOccurred
```

I haven't tried `chrome.declarativeWebRequest` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest because it's for Beta and Dev channels only.

Is it really possible or did I have mistake in using it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10257301)

Comment: @wOxxOm enter chrome://extensions/, then click Background link that shown below your extension item. then console window for it will open.

Comment: sorry, no, I mean I've checked on background console, but the log for those `webRequest` listeners not appear, meaning the event not even triggered.

Comment: Maybe you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing it? Or maybe your background script is incporrectly declared in manifest.json? Otherwise it would be a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the "webRequestBlocking" permission to your manifest.json file.

According to the documentation the callback uses a blocking event handler that requires the "webRequest" as well as the "webRequestBlocking" permission in order to work.

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples